# React styled components add custom logic for props?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to replicate this active class logic into my styled component, but I don't understand how to write it.

Here is the regular code

```
        <section className="slider">
          {slides.map((s, i) => (
            <div className={i === curr ? "slide active" : "slide"} key={s.title}>
              <div>
                <h1>{s.title}</h1>
                <h2>{s.subtitle}</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </section>
```

I'm trying to replicate this `className={i === curr ? "slide active" : "slide"}` but with styled components.

The regular css is just this

```
                .slide {
                    opacity: 0;
                    transition: .3s ease;
                }

                .slide.active {
                    opacity: 1;
                    transition-duration: .2s;
                }
```

But in styled components, how is this possible to implement?

Example in styled components

```
 <Slide curr={curr}></Slider>
```

Then the styling

```
 const Slide = styled.div`
 transition: 0.3s;
 opacity: ${({curr}) => (curr ? '1' : '0')};
 `
```

The problem is I can't check if `i === curr` for the prop in styled components, so I don't know how else I would write this?

Comment: Can't you compare it directly in the component prop ? `<Slide curr={i==curr} />`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
opacity: ${({active}) => (active ? '1' : '0')};
```

then

```
slides.map((s, i) => <Slide active={curr === i}>...</Slide>)
```